# how to install avxsynth on centos?

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

i am using centos 6 x86_64 and  i am trying to install avxsynth for centos, but it always failed

from [link](https://github.com/avxsynth/avxsynth/wiki/System-Setup) page  i found that i have to install

> automake libtool
>   MPlayer sudo apt-get install mplayer
>
> Log4CPP sudo apt-get install liblog4cpp5-dev liblog4cpp5
>
> Cairo sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
>
> Pango sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev
>
> LibJPEG sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev (required to build the frame capture plugin)
>
> QT sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev(required if you want to build the GUI app AvxEdit).
>
> ffms2 sudo apt-get install libffms2-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev
>
> libpostproc-dev libswscale-dev (required to build the ffms2 plugin)

but in yum that packages are not exists,

and for compile ffms itself it always failed, i am confused , please help!